# Methods of constructing input and ouput vectors in Reinforcement Learning with approximation function learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, feature-selection

Give the one-hot state vector $\boldsymbol{x}(s)=[x_1(s),x_2(s)]^T$ and action spaces $A(s)=\{a_1,a_2\}$ for all $s$.

In a course, I was taught to construct "stack" input vectors like $[x_{11}(s,a),x_{21}(s,a),x_{12}(s,a),x_{22}(s,a)]^T$ with $x_{ij}(s)=1$ if the action is $a_j$ and the state is $s_i$, and the output is just $q(s,a)$.

However, in DQN, the input vector is $\boldsymbol{x}(s)=[x_1(s),x_2(s)]^T$, and the output vector is $[q(s,a_1),q(s,a_2)]$.

My question is: What are the usual ways to construct input and ouput vectors in  Reinforcement Learning to learn the action value function q(s,a)? Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build a function like $Q(s,a)$ using DQN, you have the problem that given 100 actions, you'll need 100 forward pass of your network

Now, since neural networks can handle multiple outputs, we usually (not always, for example not for continuous action spaces) just  model $Q(s)$, where the network outputs all the Qs for all the actions. This way, you only need 1 forward pass to get all the Qs.

Also, bare in mind that using a 1-hot encoding, even though they make perfect sense for tabular cases, as state representation might not be the best for neural networks, as it will be much harder for them to generalize, and you'll have a giant input space

Comment: OP's examples are actually a Q table implemented via a weights matrix, presumably as a teaching method, or to allow later upgrade of the implementation without re-writing from scratch.

Comment: @NeilSlater yes, i agree with you, but i don't get your point... do you think the answer is OT or what?...

Comment: I was addressing your last para - you are critiquing approach explained in the question, but I think OP is coming from a very different starting place, and it might be an idea to unpick that to help them understand your advice.

Comment: @NeilSlater oh ok I see your point, I'll add a note on that, you're right

Comment: Thank you for your answers! May I know what OP and OT stand for?

Comment: @fermented_bean OP=original poster, OT=off topic

Comment: Oh I see, thought they were the abbreviation of the approaches. Btw, could I ask more about the case where the action is continuous? In such a case is learning q(s,a) the only choice? (a becomes a continuous feature or so)

Comment: @fermented_bean in that case you have a problem that even though defining $Q(s,a)$ might work, you  have to keep in mind that Qs are expected returns under a policy... but you don't have a policy... so you have to resort either to methods like DDPG/TD3/SAC, or to approaches that changes completely the paradigm like CMA-ES/CEM